# Compare issues of different datatypes

Tags: python, string-comparison

I'm trying to parse text file witch one looks like:

> 1;electrical engineer;0;90
>
> 2;mechanic;0;77
>
> 3;scientist;1;71
>
> 4;computers specialist;1;90

To have an option to separate needed elements. There is a my code below:

```
with open('employee.txt', 'r') as employee_list:
    for employee in employee_list.readlines():
        fields = employee.split(';')
        if fields[1] == 'electrical engineer' and fields[3] >= 60:
            print(fields)
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Also if Im going to :

```
if fields[1] == 'electrical engineer':
    print(fields)
```

I get my 'electrical engineer' string witch looks like:

> ['1', 'electrical engineer', '0', '90\n']

And I see what **fields[3]** is a string element, so Im trying:

```
if fields[1] == 'electrical engineer' and int(fields[3] >= 60):
    print(fields)
```

But just getting the same error

***Will appreciate any advices***

Comment: try: int(fields[3].rstrip()) >= 60 -- rstrip() to remove the \n trailing

Comment: @darc Yeah, it helps, can you add this as an answer, so I can close this question ?

Comment: alternatively, change `fields = employee.split(';')` to `fields = employee.strip().split(';')`

Comment: @JeffXiao answer will also work just don't forget to change the condition int(fields[3]) >=6 instead of int(fields[3] >= 60)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` method returns list of strings. `fields[3]` is a string. You have to convert it to `int`. Try:

```
int(fields[3].rstrip()) >= 60
```

-- `rstrip()` to remove the `\n` trailing